# How to get list of child from parent id in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with java.
I'm having parent as A and child B.
parent A has more than one child. I want to generate list of child using parent A's id.
any leads or tutorial will be helpful.

Thx in adv.

Comment: Store `parent: parent_id` in all nodes. then query by `parent_id: query_parent_id`

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan How to use that in java format?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-parent.html) is the relevant documentation.

And you can use something similar to:

```
GET /library/chapter/_search
{
  "size": 5, 
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "book",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "_id": {
            "value": "book1"
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

`book` is the parent and `chapter` is the children. Note one important bit: the URL refers to the children type `GET /library/chapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticsearch based query would be something like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "A",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "_id": {
                        "value": "ID"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the java based implementation.

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(JoinQueryBuilders.hasParentQuery("A", QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id", "ID"), true))
                .build();
System.out.println(elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(query, Infections.class).getTotalHits());
```

I am printing hits you can do whatever you want.

I hope this will fulfill your requirement.